# Swift 3.0 Error: Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' when setting a Dictionary value

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift3

I've got this method below which inserts a value into a dictionary. In Swift 2.x, it worked as is.  When switching to Swift 3, I get the "Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'" error.

Can anyone help me out in understanding why. Thanks

```
private func GetNames() -> AnyObject? {
    var returnList : [NSDictionary] = []
    let list = self.Names as! [NSDictionary]
    for name in list {
        var dict : Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = [:]
        dict["id"] = name["id"]      // <-- ******Error*******
        dict["name"] = name["name"]  // <-- ******Error*******
        returnList.append(dict as NSDictionary)
    }
    return returnList as AnyObject
}
```

Comment: What is that . after name["id"]?

Comment: Are you trying to access element from name["id"] ? What is that . after name["id"]?

Comment: That was a typo when I was putting in the // comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3 `String` is type of `Structure`, so it will not work with `NSObject` and you have declare dictionary thats key type is `NSObject` that is the reason you are getting that error. To solve the error simply change type of dictionary to `[String:Any]` form `[NSObject:AnyObject]` and you all set to go.

```
var dict : [String:Any] = [:]
```

**Note:** Also in Swift don't use `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` use Swift's native type dictionary and array.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because Swift 3 needs to know all types which are subscripted by key or index.

Using Foundation collection types is counterproductive because they lack exactly that type information the compiler needs.

Returning an optional `AnyObject` rather than the distinct (non-optional) `[[String:Any]]` is counterproductive, too.

The solution is to use only (as) specific (as possible) native Swift types.

```
private func getNames() -> [[String:Any]] {
    var returnList = [[String:Any]]()
    let list = self.Names as! [[String:Any]]
    for name in list {
        var dict = [String:Any]()
        dict["id"] = name["id"]
        dict["name"] = name["name"]
        returnList.append(dict)
    }
    return returnList
}
```

or *swiftier* if it's guaranteed that both keys `name` and `id` always exist

```
private func getNames() -> [[String:Any]] {
    let list = Names as! [[String:Any]]

    return list.map { ["id" : $0["id"]!, "name" : $0["name"]!]  }
}
```